1С Запоминание источника бумаги при печати по условию
Будьте добры, подскажите логику, как можно заставить программу запоминать источник бумаги для определенного условия.
Есть документ с реквизитом "ТипОплаты", который может быть либо "Нал", либо "Безнал". Нужно, чтобы при "Нал" печать осуществлялась из ЛОТОК (там листы А5), а при "Безнал" из КАССЕТА (там листы А4).
Через код удается дотянуться до любого параметра из формы "Параметры страницы" КРОМЕ Источника бумаги.
Выгуглил, что источник бумаги запоминается вместе со всеми настройками печати в "ИмяПараметровПечати", хранится во внутреннем кэше 1С. Попробовал назначить каждому условию новые имена, полагая, что таким образом у каждого условия создастся своя персональная ячейка для хранения и подстановки персональных параметров, но не сработало.
Помимо этого, даже принудительная смена источника в "Параметры страницы" не дает результата, принтер упорно берет бумагу из одного и того же места.
Поделитесь идеями, что можно сделать, чего не хватает или что идет не так.
